# Выделение ошибок на странице, нужна замена Orphus

Tags: javascript

На многих сайтах сейчас есть функция выделения ошибок и отправки сообщения владельцу с помощью выделения текста и нажатия сочетания Ctrl+Enter. Родоначальником этой темы является сервис Orphus.ru Ему уже сто лет в обед, он устарел и внешне, и технически. Есть ли какая-то замена, есть ли сервис который так же легко устанавливается?
Понятно, что вроде не сложно все реализовать самому, но хочется что-то симпатичное готовое. Хотя бы готовый шаблон+скрипт, если нет сервиса.

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативы есть, например эта: https://revisionme.com/#/start
Есть даже демка, где можно посмотреть пример работы:
[image: См. пример работы]
[Источник скриншота](https://widget.revisionme.com/)

или эта https://github.com/psmb/typo-reporter - на основе орфуса.

Сам проект orphus судя по всему перекочевал на гитхаб:
https://github.com/ProgerXP/Orphus и поддерживается его изобретателем.

Я пробовал ставить orphus как сервис, но письма не приходили ко мне, как бы я не старался решить эту проблему (потому что не происходит регистрания на orphus.ru). Альтернативы мне не понравилось.

Всё таки проще и лучше всего взять с [гитхаба](https://github.com/ProgerXP/Orphus), там есть детальнейшая инструкция о том как использовать. Письма отправляются со своего сервера. Я например легко настроил использование SMTP - предусмотрено использование любой своей функции вместо mail().

[image: См. скриншот работающего примера]
[Источник скриншота](https://goodprogrammist.ru/)

Comment: Добавте примеры из ранее данной ссыки прямо в ответ, тогда можете привести ссылку в качестве источника.

Comment: @GoodProgrammist, для какой цели ваш сайт хочет знать местоположение посетителей?

Comment: @0xdb, сайт приводится только как демонстрация сайта, где прикручен orphus. Я не думаю, что это можно считать источником. В данном случае просто скриншота было бы достаточно (ИМХО).

Comment: @insolor, Местоположение используется для демонстрации возможности отображения карты на странице контактов, в зависимости от местоположения. Не обязательно соглашаться делиться своим местоположением, это добровольно. Карта имеет настройки по умолчанию. В принципе сам сайт был создан для того чтобы на нём делать различные демонстрации.

Comment: @0xdb, укажу как источник скриншота, потому что всё таки лучше увидеть в деле, чем на картинках, так будет ближе к мысли.

Comment: @GoodProgrammist А что это даст? После каждой вашей правки срабатывает тревога, так как ваш ник=имя сайта. У хороших програмистов есть хорошая традиция, обмениваться кодом, а не ссылками и картинками.